# Eclipse Content Assist ignoring spelling errors

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, content-assist

I recently bought a new keyboard and keep making spelling errors, closing the Content Assist midway. Is there any option within Eclipse preferences that let it stay open if at least some of the members have been found and spelled correctly?

For example if it suggests "myMethod()" and I write "myMb", Content Assist closes.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not feature a spelling error correcting content assist. I am also not aware of any plugins that do this.

What comes somewhat close is [Eclipse Code Recommenders](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/)’ [Subwords completion](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#intelligent-code-completion), which allows you to put in substrings of the method name, e.g. `myMd` would complete to `myMethod()`. However, when there are characters not part of the method’s name in your search string, the method won’t be found.